# Projection of the $XY$ plane.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Is there a way to project the infinite Complex plane to either the Poincare disk or the unit disk - for all values of $x + iy ?$

Comment: What is the difference between the Poincaré disk and the unit disk?

Comment: What do you mean by "project": will a bijective continuous function suffice? Does the "unit disk" include or exclude its boundary?

Comment: I think I meant inside the unit circle ~

Comment: @zoli-don't know and trying to learn about projections of the XY plane ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bijective continuous function from the complex plane to the interior of the unit disk, i.e. $|w|<1$:

$$f(u)=\frac{u}{1+|u|}$$

where $|u|$ is the modulus (distance from the origin) of $u$. In other words, for real $\theta$ and nonnegative $r$,

$$f\left(re^{i\theta}\right)=\frac{re^{i\theta}}{1+r}$$

Any branch cut (such as $\arg(z)=0$ or $\arg(z)=\pm\pi$) can be chosen for the argument function: the choice will not change the function and will leave the function continuous. Even though $\theta$ is not well-defined at zero the function still is well-defined, with $f(0)=0$ whatever the choice of $\theta$.

This function projects any complex number to another one with the same argument but inside the unit circle. For example, the unit disk is projected to the disk with radius $\frac 12$. The inverse function from the interior of the unit disk to the complex plane is

$$f^{-1}(u)=\frac{u}{1-|u|}$$
or
$$f^{-1}\left(re^{i\theta}\right)=\frac{re^{i\theta}}{1-r}$$

---

I could even argue that this function is a "projection."

[image]d

In this diagram, the eye is in the complex $xy$ plane, with the vertical axis the $z$ plane. We have place the eye so our complex point is on the positive horizontal axis, let's call it $r$. Then we take the intersection of the line from your complex point to the point $(0,0,1)$ with the cone with vertex at $(0,0,0)$ with upward slope $1$. We then *project* that point back down to the complex plane.

That final point is the value of our function. Thus our function $f$ is a projection of the convex plane onto the tip of a cone followed by a projection onto the interior of the unit disk.

---

Here is a graphic from the OP showing how the grid of the Cartesian coordinate system maps into the unit circle.

[image]

Comment: That is a very good answer and I just wanted to know how to "stuff" any point in the XY plane to inside of the unit circle or disk. I will try to plug in some numbers !

Comment: In the f(u), am I to assume that u=x+iy and |u| is (xx+yy)^.5 ???

Comment: @ArtLawrence: Yes, that is correct, though I would write $|u|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. If you like that format, write $$f(x+yi)=\frac{x+yi}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ or perhaps $$f(x+yi)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{y}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}i$$

Comment: Thanks Rory-I put in + and - values for many x and y and the f(u) works!

Comment: I made an image but could not figure out how to show it - I am new and lack experience with this site :(

Comment: Now I find that I don't have enough activity to post an image :(

Comment: @ArtLawrence: If you place your image on a web site (such as imgur.com) and give me the URL, I'll look at it and add it to my answer if it is appropriate, or even add another answer if appropriate.

Comment: Here is one Link.[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/yOcVico.png)   And another.<a href="http://imgur.com/yOcVico"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOcVico.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>.................Thank you for your time ~

Comment: @ArtLawrence: I have added the graphic to the end of my answer. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: You have answered my question and the graphic proves it-we are done :)