# Geometric significance of a complex chart on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I started to read about Complex Charts and encountered the following complex chart:

$$\phi(x, y) = \frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\frac{y}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$.

I can check that it is a homeomorphism. It is easy to see that this is injective as it is $z \to \frac{z}{1+|z|}$ which preserves lines and also if $z_1$ and $\lambda z_1$ are two on a line then because $a \to \frac{a}{1+a}$ is injective for positive $a$ we get that $\phi$ is injective and so on.

But I would have never thought of this chart. There must be a geometric significance to this or just significance. I can see it is sort of a contraction and the further points get pulled in more drastically but can we say something more concrete?

Comment: Yes, this is a projection from the complex plane to the open unit disk. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1381089/269764)

Comment: Note this differs from the behavior of the map $z \mapsto z/|z|$, as this map sends any positive real number to $1$ and is thus not injective.